# Remove newline from beam.io.WriteToText

Tags: apache-beam

Is there a way to prevent the Apache Beam beam.io.WriteToText function from creating a new line after each item? I would like to be able to output only certain data using conditional statements, however, the lines that are not returned from the conditional statements result in a blank line being written to the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set append_trailing_newlines=False

For example:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    ...
    p_to_write | WriteToText(file_path_to_write_to, append_trailing_newlines=False)
```

See documentation [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.5.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.WriteToText).